# "LIMIT 5,10" returns 9 rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

http://666kb.com/i/c6e4rv80gz9yrn9h5.png

Check out my image, I limited the query for just 5 entry but it returns with 9 rows? What is the problem, I could not get it.

Comment: You don't ask for a limit of 5 - you ask for a limit of 5,10.  Additionally you're not getting 9 rows back - you're getting 10 rows back.

Comment: Yes but in the body of the question you say you ask for just 5 entries. I was pointing out that that's not what you wrote in your limit statement and it should be a red flag to you that you actually got back 10 rows and you have 10 in your limit statement.  After seeing this you might be able to realize that you're probably not making a correct assumption about how the limit statement operates.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With mysql, the [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) parameters are `offset, row_count`, but the *first* parameter is optional - crazy, but true!

So when you have *two* parameters, the first is the starting row, the second is the number of rows.

You asked for `LIMIT 5, 10` which means *10 rows, starting from row 5* (not rows 5 to 10).

You are not the first, and you won't be the last, person to be confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Limit function Syntax are:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
LIMIT Rows start , Quantity of Rows for display;
```

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
LIMIT 2 , 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest go to this link [LIMIT in mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp), after I browsed through the above comments, I have to point out, that `limit 5, 10` returns 10 rows and it starts from row 6. 
**LIMIT**: 
`limit 10 offset 5` and `limit 5, 10`, both of them return **10** rows, starting from row **6**.
 I strongly recommend go to the above link.

Hope it helps!!